# Diagonal is closed implications

Tags: general-topology

(A) The diagonal $\Delta = \{(x,x) \mid x \in X\}$ is closed in $X \times X$.

(B) For $x \in X$, let $\mathcal{U}$ be the family of all open neighbourhoods of $x$. Then the intersection of the closures of all these open neighbourhoods in $\mathcal{U}$ is just $\{x\}$.

How to show A and B are equivalent directly without using $X$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose A holds. Fix $x \in X$ and consider $\bigcap \{\overline{U}: U \in \mathcal{U}\}$. It's clear that $x$ is in this intersection as $x \in U\subseteq \overline{U}$ for all $U \in \mathcal{U}$. Now, if $y \neq x$, we can say that $(x,y) \notin \Delta$ and as A holds, this set is closed so we have a basic product open $U \times V$ containing $(x,y)$ such that $(U \times V) \cap \Delta = \emptyset$. In particular, $y \in V$ and $x \in U$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$ (as  $z \in U \cap V \to (z,z) \in (U \times V) \cap \Delta = \emptyset$), and $V$ witnesses that $y \notin \overline{U}$, so $y$ is not in the intersection. So $\bigcap \{\overline{U}: U \in \mathcal{U}\} = \{x\}$ follows.

The reverse is very similar, and also shows the quite direct connection to Hausdorffness... Both A and B are very simple reformulations of it. For if we know B we know that any $y \neq x$ is not in that intersection so $y$ has a neighbourhood that misses some neighbourhood of $x$ (and we already have Hausdorff again) and we make a product neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ that misses $\Delta$ again etc.